# auto reschedule job after server down by quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

The requirement is simple, say server need to set variable salesOffRatio to 0.8 between 01-01 and 01-10 total ten days. And "salesOffRatio = 0.8" is a job which triggered by a quartz trigger at 01-10 00:00:00. The problem is server restart at 01-05 due to power lack, variable salesOffRatio will be not 0.8 anymore, it will become to init value and the trigger will not fire because 01-10 00:00:00 has been passed.

Is there a solution to solve this kind problem? I need auto re-schedule because the job need to set a state for a very long duration and server have to restart in that duration due to maintain operation or something like that which can not be avoid.

misfire with jdbcJobStore seems ok, set a proper misfire threshold. But it is universal, in this situation, I need to set distinct value for each job ( salesOffRatio1, salesOffRatio2...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few solutions I came up with:

1. Your `salesOffRatio` should survive server restart. Store it in a database, file, whatever. Instead of modifying the variable, update your database in a job.
2. If your use-case is so simple, why not create a function

   ```
   double getSalesOffRatio(Date effectiveDate)
   ```

   that will return correct `salesOffRatio` value depending on `effectiveDate` passed? In other words just compute `salesOffRatio` every time you need it. BTW the extra argument will make testing easier compared to reading current system time inside `getSalesOffRatio()`.
3. You can use XML scheduling plugin or some other way to reschedule all jobs every time server restarts. By default job is deleted after it was triggered (`durable` property) so by carefully configuring misfire policy, scheduler will refire all your jobs on startup. Brittle in my opinion.

Final thought: talking about misfire policies, have you considered what will happen if restart occurs *when the job was scheduled*?

Comment: In my practical project, the data needs to change is too many, wrap them in functions is impractical. And they are meta-data which shared by other servers, replicate them in db is trouble, it involves a problem when the meta-data changed, I need to update all replicated ones.

Comment: I think the only way is to check-and-reschedule manually when server restart. All changes triggered by jobs will not persistent and don't need be in transaction. So restart is no harm to executing jobs

Answer (score 0):

Either you could persist the value of 'salesOffRatio' to a database or a file, and then rather than initialising it to a default value, you could initialise it to the stored value.

Alternatively you could run a program on startup to re-run all quartz triggers (or just those in the jobgroup which you need for updating these values).